How to detect that a text node is inside a tag
I have html file
    <div>1. <span id="el1"> hello </span> world</div>

    <div>

      <span id="el2"> first part</span>
      <span id="el3"> second part </span><br />

    </div>

I have "hello" text node
document.querySelector("#el1").childNodes[0] // hello
document.querySelector("#el2").childNodes[0].splitText(6) // split text node ("first" and "part")

how can I check if text node is wrapped by any tag.
I can also have text node "part" in <span>first part </span> (so there can be two text nodes "first" and "part")  result of js splitText method.
How to cover all edge cases?
I tried this to compare it
document.querySelector("#el1").textContent.trim() === document.querySelector("#el1").childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()

I expect to get boolean value true or false when comparing it.

so in your examples, #el1 hello is true and #el2 hello is false?

after the split method, if we have two text nodes and we select any one of them, it's false

If indeed so, all you need is to check if the text node parent has only 1 child.


function isTextWrapped(textnode) {
  return textnode.parentElement.childNodes.length === 1
}



var el1Text = document.querySelector("#el1").childNodes[0] // hello
var el2Text = document.querySelector("#el2").childNodes[0].splitText(6) // split text node ("first" and "part")

console.log(isTextWrapped(el1Text))
console.log(isTextWrapped(el2Text))
<div>1. <span id="el1"> hello </span> world</div>

<div>

  <span id="el2"> first part</span>
  <span id="el3"> second part </span><br />

</div>




it is good approach, but if we have some empty (blank) text nodes we can filter them and check for length?
document.querySelector("#el2").childNodes[0].splitText(0) // make blank text node at beggining
el2Text.parentElement.childNodes // [text, text]

el2Text.parentElement.childNodes // [text, text] first text node empty, we get second as text.
I know there is a Node.normalize function for such a case but I can have splitted text node and I don't want to use this method. It seems we need to check any non empty text node before and after that text node or filter for not empty node.

there is another property for each text node and it's called wholeText - maybe that helps?
